# Firebase storage how to get uploading images progress in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get progress of uploading images and I saw the explanation link below. However what I want to do is uploading multiple images.

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495883/how-to-link-firebase-download-file-with-a-progress-view)

I implemented like this to upload images.

```
 for image in imagesArray {
            let postRef = ref.child("post").child(uid)("images")
            let autoId = postRef.childByAutoId().key
            let childStorageRef = storageRef.child("images").child(autoId)

            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                childStorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error")
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let imageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                            let val = [autoId: imageUrl]
                            postRef.updateChildValues(val)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

I tried call `observe(.progress)`

But there is only `childStorageRef.observe(<#T##keyPath: KeyPath<StorageReference, Value>##KeyPath<StorageReference, Value>#>, options: <#T##NSKeyValueObservingOptions#>, changeHandler: <#T##(StorageReference, NSKeyValueObservedChange<Value>) -> Void#>)`

So, I don't know how to get progress like link.
How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Swift- 5 Easy Way

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.reference().child("folderName/file.jpg");
let localFile: NSURL = // get a file;

// Upload the file to the path "folderName/file.jpg"
let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil)
uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in            
    print(snapshot.progress) // NSProgress object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. First, create a variable of your query:**
(Just add "let uploadTask = " before the query)

Example: let uploadTask = childStorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in...

**2. Then you can call this observers:**
(Observe progress)

```
uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
```

or

(Observe when success)

```
uploadTask.observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
```

or

(Observe if fail)

```
uploadTask.observe(.failure, handler: { (snapshot) in
```